# Maximum average Subarray

Tags: arrays

I am working on a Leetcode question and not able to clear all the test cases. 
It says time limit has been exceeded for one of the solution

Given an array consisting of n integers, find the contiguous subarray of given length k that has the maximum average value. And you need to output the maximum average value.

Example 1:
Input: [1,12,-5,-6,50,3], k = 4
Output: 12.75
Explanation: Maximum average is (12-5-6+50)/4 = 51/4 = 12.75

My solution to the question:

```
class Solution {
    public double findMaxAverage(int[] nums, int k) {
        double average = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double temp = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for(int j=i;j<nums.length;j++)
            {
                count ++;
                sum += nums[j];
                if(count ==k)
                {
                    temp = (double)(sum)/k;
                    average = Math.max(temp,average);

                }
            }
        }


        return average;
    }
}
```

I was able to clear 69/123 test cases. But failing for other where it says time limit has exceeded.

Please help in fixing my code.

Comment: You're going to need to improve your time complexity from O(n^2). In other words, find a way to avoid using a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed-up your code.

For instance:

```
class Solution {
    public double findMaxAverage(int[] nums, int k) {
        double average = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double temp = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int imax = nums.length-k;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                {
                    sum += nums[j];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sum += nums[i - 1 + k] - nums[i - 1];
            }
            average = Math.max((double)(sum)/k,average);
        }
        return average;
    }
}
```